# Save PSQL run time parameter as a variable

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to set `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to be equal to the run time parameter `max_parallel_workers` in the current session only.

I want this to be applicable across numerous different machines so instead of hard-coding a value I want it to be directly relational to this other run time parameter.

Is there a way I can do this? I don't seem to be able to create a variable and set it to be the value of max_parallel_workers like such:

```
\set test_var max_parallel_workers;
```

Comment: Do you want to change that permanently (e.g. using `ALTER SYSTEM`)  or just for the current session?

Comment: Just the current session - I'll edit the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a variable:

```
select set_config('max_parallel_workers_per_gather', 
                   current_setting('max_parallel_workers'), false);
```